# Android app not recognizing auto completed words on device

Tags: java, android, xml

I recently created an app that took user input from an Edittext field and compares it to a predefined string.  in the emulator it works perfect but when I put it on my android device and test it there,  it seems to not recognize words that were auto-completed by the device (i.e. when i type in part of the word suggestions are filled in and selected by me). It compares false when it should be true.

Why is this happening?  is there an xml tag i can integrate that takes away the auto-suggest feature for the edit text field?

here is what my edit text xml looks like:

```
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/st5ans"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/form_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/input_height"
        android:textSize="@dimen/statenamesize"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/maingamespaceing"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/state5"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/st4ans"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        />
```

I compare them like this:

```
 EditText ans1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.st1ans);
        EditText ans2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.st2ans);
        EditText ans3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.st3ans);
        EditText ans4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.st4ans);
        EditText ans5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.st5ans);
        EditText[] ans={ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, ans5};
        int count=0;
        int number=0;
        String feed="";

        //this loop tallys up all of our correct answers and then builds
        // feedback for wrong answers to give to
        //the user, using our data hashmap
            for (EditText y : ans)
            {
                String temp=y.getText().toString();
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(stats[number%stats.length].getText().toString())))
                {
                    count += 1;
                } else {
                    if (firstpass)
                    {
                        feed += "         The capitol of  " +
                                drawlist.get(drawn.get(number)) + " is " +
                                data.get(drawlist.get(drawn.get(number))) + "  " + "\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        feed += "          "+drawlist.get(drawn.get(number))+
                                " is the capitol of "+
                                data.get(drawlist.get(drawn.get(number))) + "  " + "\n";
                    }
                }

                number += 1;

            }
```

temp being the Edittext value to string (String temp=y.getText().toString();)

Comment: Please put the entire code snippet on where you are comparing the strings so we see what exactly you are trying to do, and which listener event are you listening to.

Comment: Where are you comparing the hardcoded string to the text field?

Comment: ok here is the comparing snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works on emulator but not in your device, there must be some discrepancy with the device's data. Make sure you're not comparing against a blank string or some other non-EditText related issue.

Comment: this kinda solved it,  the dumb auto correct was putting a white space char in the string,  so i had to modify with a .trim() method  thanks

Answer (score -1):

You want to use an [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html). It uses an adapter to match the input to possible suggestions.